# Semi-private enum values

Tags: c++, design-patterns, enums

Is it possible to have an enumeration where (some) members are accessible from user-code and others are reserved for the implementation?

Here is a minified example of the situation I'm trying to handle: I have a benchmarking framework where I instrument the functions given by a user. To check the sanity of execution the user should report whether execution happened correctly or not, hence a `return_code` enumeration is created:

```cpp
enum return_code {
  ok,
  error,
  execution_timeout,
  waiting_time_exceeded
};
```

The last two enumerators should not be available to the user, i.e. I'm the one responsible to check if there's a timeout or the processing queue never got to executing the function on time.

My current handling of the situation is to split the enumerators in a private and public interface:

```cpp
namespace detail {
  enum return_code_internal {
      ok,
      error,
      execution_timeout,
      waiting_time_exceeded
  };
}

enum return_code {
    ok,
    error
};
```

So `return_code::ok` maps to `detail::return_code_internal::ok` and same happens for `error`, while the "internal" enumerators are not visible to the user. This works but forces me to jump through hoops when converting between the two types since they are not symmetric (one has 2 members while the other has 4). **Is there a better way?**

P.S I know that in C++ enumerators have the same visibility. I'm looking for a technique that would simulate having two `enum` members as "public", while the other two are "private" (or for internal use).

Comment: Use a class with `static` members as you enumerations?

Comment: @NathanOliver That sounds doable. You mean I'd have public/private members and then classes of the internal implementation would be friends of the "enumerator class" to be able to access the internals right ? I'd appreciate a rough sketch in an answer so that I won't get lost in the details

Comment: Another option is `enum class return_code : int { ok, error };` and then `namespace detail { constexpr return_code execution_timeout{2}; constexpr return_code waiting_time_exceeded{3}; }`.  Sequestering your "internal use" values in `detail`.  A variation of Nathan's suggestion, really.

Comment: @Eljay that looks comfy to implement! But isn't it undefined behavior? I mean enums don't have bounds checking and weird effects can be built upon that, but wouldn't it cause side effects?

Comment: Yes, enums have "bit range" bounds checking.  The `: int` forces the underlying type to be an `int`, and not do the "bit range" calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a class with static members as the enumeration.  This lets you have public and private members.  The only catch is you would need to grant friendship to all of the things that need access to those private variables.  That could look like:

```
struct return_code
{
    constexpr static int ok = 0;
    constexpr static int error = 1;
private:
    constexpr static int execution_timeout = 2;
    constexpr static int waiting_time_exceeded = 3;
    
    friend xxx;
    friend yyy;
    friend zzz;
};
```